# Maximize the inradius given the base and the area of the triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, contest-math

BdMO 2013 Secondary:

> A triangle has base of length 8 and area 12. What is the radius of the largest circle 
>   that can be inscribed in this triangle?

Let $A,r,s$ denote the area,inradius and semiperimeter respectively.Then we have that

$A=rs$

$\implies 12=r\dfrac{8+b+c}{2}$  [$b,c$ are the lengths of two other sides]

The only thing that can be said about $b+c$ is that it must be greater than $8$.Also,to maximize $r$,we need to minimize $b+c$.Also,$b+c$ can be rewritten as $8+2y$ for some $y$.But I am unable to infer anything else from this information.A **hint** will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you can compute the height of the triangle too

Comment: @Mark,yes,I noted that too,but it yielded nothing good.

Comment: @Mark,oh,it seems like we do need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b+c to be minimum b=c should hold. So b=c=5.(by simple Pythagoras). So r=1.34.

Comment: Can you explain why we must equalize b and c to minimize their sum?

Comment: Got it(I thinks so.Please tell me if this is correct).To minimize the sum,we must minimize their difference as well.Hence,b=c.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes your thinking is correct. there are some more ways to prove that. try to find one more method.

Comment: How about AM-GM?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is correct but I think you can equalise the sums from the following:

Since you know the hight of the triangle is 3, you can write a general expression for length of the two sides $b$ and $c$ in terms of $x$. 
$$ b^2=9+(x)^2 \;\; \text{ and } \;\; c^2=9+(8-x)^2 $$
Minimising the sum $b+c$ is the same to minimising the sum of the squares so adding the two above equations then differentiating gives:
$$ (b^2+c^2)'=2 x-2 (8-x)$$ 
which after solving for a minimum gives $x=4$ meaning that the perpendicular must be the in the centre of the base hence it much be an isosceles triangle thus $b=c$.

Like I said not sure if this is a valid way to show it, just seemed to work.

Comment: I can't comment because I don't know calculus(and contest maths don't accept calculus).Nevertheless,thanks for your effort.

Comment: @rah4927 Really, contest maths don't accept calculus? That would be a major problem for me, since I was planning to give RMO this year, and I solve many problems using the wonderful tools of calculus.

Comment: I think you need to justify "minimising $b+c$ is the same as minimising the sum of the squares"

Comment: @Sawarnik,It perhaps differs from place to place(or contest to contest),but contest problems are usually designed so as to be solvable without needing the slightest bit of calculus.Many contests I know of don't accept solutions that use calculus.

Comment: @Mark,$b^2+c^2=(b+c)^2/2 +(b-c)^2/2$.To minimize this,we need to minimize $b+c$.Am I right?